# Parsing & Replacing Values in a String

Tags: java, parsing

*Questions like this one have been answered but none helped me understand and decide the best suited way to do this in my case.*

The idea:

```
Input: 15k+5b-1m
Ouput: 15000+5000000000-1000000
```

Basically replacing k by 1,000 - m by 1,000,000 and b by 1,000,000,000 and multiply it to the value it is attached to.

How I thought I'd do it:

```
Using 2 StringTokenizer, one to parse math signs +,-,*,/ and one to parse
letter k,m,b that I call on every element the first parser got.
```

So if we apply the algorithm we'd have for my example:

```
Str Input = 15k+5b-1m
StringTokenizer math_token= new StringTokenizer(source, Input);
while (math_token.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            while(math_token.hasMoreElements())
            {
                 Str token_value = math_token.nextElement();
                 parse_letters(token_value) and change values...
            }
            math_token.nextToken();
            format stuff for the final string
        }
```

So it goes like:

```
15k -> 15 -> 15000
```

Comment: Would `input.replace("k", "000").replace("b", "000000000").replace("m", "000000")` not suffice?

Comment: "Questions like this one..." Would you care to link to any of them?

Comment: Wow - I didn't know this existed (well deep down I knew but nevermind - had to get adviced), thanks alot - it's perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you could replace `b` with nine zeros `m` with six zeros and `k` with three zeros. Also, by convention, Java variable names start with a lower-case letter. Something like,

```
String input = "15k+5b-1m";
input = input.replace("b", "000000000").replace("m", "000000")
        .replace("k", "000");
System.out.println(input);
```

which outputs (as requested)

```
15000+5000000000-1000000
```